# Simple multivariable calculucs problem. Is solution in handout wrong?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Function is given by:

$$(, ) = ^2 + ^2$$

Gradient is $$(2x, 2y)$$

Contour lines are given by:

$$f(x,y) = c$$ with $$ = \sqrt{c}$$

$$y(x) = \pm  \sqrt{c-x^2}$$

then a vector tangent to contour lines is given by:

$$t = \left(1, \pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{ c-x^2 }}\right)$$

The solution gives the scalar product between gradient and tangent as:

$$t \cdot g = 1\cdot2x \pm \frac{2x\cdot2y(x)}{\sqrt{c-x^2}}$$

Where does the $2x$ come from in the second summand of the scalar product? Shouldn't it be only $x$?

Comment: Normally we use * for convolution, for scalar product and normal products you can use \cdot instead.

Comment: But concerning the question. I don't see why this would be the correct answer. There should not be a second 2.